# 12.10 nautilus on dell xps 12 does not work

Tags: nautilus

I have installed 12.10 on a new Dell XPS 12 ultrabook. Everything seems to work properly right now, including the touch screen, except for nautilus.

The left pane works properly, I can select an item on the left and the contents will show up on the right, but when I go to do anything with the contents on the right nothing happens, I can't double click to open, I can't right click to bring up a menu. I can however hold down the left button and to draw a box to select more than one item, but I can't do anything with the selected items.

I did not have these problems when I tried 12.04, but unfortunately the touchscreen does not work out of the box on 12.04 and 12.10 seemed to be the faster way go.

Any ideas?

How can I log what is happening when I try to do anything in nautilus?

Comment: I have the same problem with my Dell XPS 12 - everything works fine until i touch the screen and then I am unable to click on a file in Nautilus with my touchpad. Disabling the touchpad helps. Did you use the out of the box kernel or the Sputnik one?

Answer (score 1):

I just got the XPS 12 and have the same problem.

What works for me to get around the problem:
- Try using list view mode in Nautilus
- Or try another viewer like Konqueror
- Or disable the touchscreen in udev

I think the problem is that the touchscreen driver doesn't emit TOUCH_END events and Nautilus is looking for them.  So a fix will be to have the driver send the TOUCH_END events or change Nautilus to stop looking for them.

Comment: I have found that pressing the Alt key twice will enable Nautilus to work with the trackpad again until you use the touchscreen again.